# how to get the imageID that the imagebutton holds

Tags: android, imagebutton

I am developing an android app
where there is a multiple choices question and the answers are Imagebuttons
and i need to check if the chosen answer is correct by checking the id of the drawable image
and the image in the chosen imagebutton
is there a function that can get the Id of the drawable the imageview or imagebutton holds?

Answer (score 1):

You can't "get the Id of the drawable the imageview or imagebutton holds". Check "if the chosen answer is correct by checking the id" of the `ImageButton` widget. Or, set a tag on the widgets and check that.